# Insert Data to Database Codeigniter only if item does not exit

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm having trouble trying to insert batch data.

All is fine with the insert_batch function but i would like to insert only the items that does not exist in database, not update it, just ignore and insert new items.

This is my Controller:

csv file:

```
col0,col1,col2,col3
data1,data1,data1,data1
data2,data2,data,2,data2
data3,data3,data3,data3
```

insert batch:

```
function mres($q) {
        if(is_array($q))
            foreach($q as $k => $v)
                $q[$k] = $this->mres($v); //recursive
        elseif(is_string($q))
            $q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
        return $q;
    }

function inserbatch(){
$csv = 'file.csv';              
                $arrResult = array();
                    $handle = fopen("uploads/csv/".$csv, "r");
                    if( $handle ) {
                    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $arrResult[] = array(
                                        'col0' => $row[0],
                                        'col1' => $row[1],
                                        'col2' => $row[2],
                                        'col3' => utf8_encode($row[3])
                                        );
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                    }

$final = $this->mres($arrResult);

$this->model_m->addBatch($final);


}
```

Model:

```
public function addBatch($final = array()){
if($this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $final)){
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

database:
id,col0,col1,col2,col3

col0 contain the unique value and if exist in csv file need to be skipped.

My question is how can i insert only the data that doesnt exist in database the col0 is the unique value and i think need to be like

if data from csv[col0] != database[col0] insert_batch.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you on the right path. You only need to check your db if the value exists.
Something like this:

```
    foreach(csv[col0] as $your_data)
    {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col0 = $your_data");
    $rows = $query->num_rows();

      if(!$rows)
      {
       // No record has been found so here you would write the code to insert the data
      }
    }
```